# Linebreak inside label - tikzcd package

Tags: tikz-pgf, tikz-cd

I am using `tikzcd`.
I want to use line breaks within the label of the arrows. Naively, I thought that

```
\begin{tikzcd}
  A \arrow[d, "label 1 \\ label 2"] \\
  B
\end{tikzcd}
```

would work. But it gives me

[image]

instead. How to solve this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use `\substack`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz-cd}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=large]
  A \arrow[d, "\substack{a \\ a}"] & % good
  A \arrow[d,"a \\ a" align=left] &  % bad
  A \arrow[d,"\shortstack{a\\a}"]    % ugly
\\
  B & B & B
\end{tikzcd}

\end{document}
```

[image]

If the labels are textual, use `\text` inside `\substack`. The same code as before, but with `\substack{\text{a} \\ \text{a}}` in the leftmost arrow yields

[image]

Answer (score 8):

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3cm]
        A \arrow[d, "\shortstack{label 1\\label 2}"] \\
        B
    \end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 7):

You only need to add `align=left` (or something of that sort).

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=3cm]
A \arrow[d,"label1\\ label2"align=left] \\
B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

From the pag. 13 of the guide of `tikz-cd` http://ctan.math.washington.edu/tex-archive/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikz-cd/tikz-cd-doc.pdf

[image]

I have used a matrix `2x1` (for example) to have two vertical labels. With the option `row sep=...cm` you can increase or decrease the lenght of the arrow.

[image]

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt,oneside]{book}
\usepackage{tikz-cd,amsmath}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzcd}[row sep=2cm, ampersand replacement=\&]
A \arrow[d, "{\begin{matrix} \text{label1} \\ \text{label2} \end{matrix}}
"] \\
B
\end{tikzcd}
\end{document}
```